# Rescaling simulations by machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, generative-models

I am working in the field of astrophysics. A problem that I consistently find in my projects is that I am always limited by the size of the sky simulations available for a specific observable that I am considering for my project. Simulations are crucial, in particular, to estimate covariance matrices, which are essential elements of any Bayesian inference analysis.

The tendency in the field is to have fairly-high resolution of small fractions of the sky. It is computationally very challenging to generate significantly larger sky areas (something like 1/3 of the sky, which is what would be needed for real applications). Therefore, I was wondering if there is a machine learning-based approach to **rescaling** simulations that are too small for practical uses, extending them to much larger areas. A few large-area simulations are probably computationally feasible, but I am doubtful that they could be in such a quantity to represent a decent training set for any machine learning algorithm.